# Database design: From relational database to Mongodb - many-to-many relations

Tags: mongodb, database-design, mongoengine, document-oriented-db, database

In my relational database I used to have 5 tables where 2 of them were junction tables, and the other 3 had a many-to-many relationship.

The 3 tables were Bus, seat and passenger (and passengers could change seat for one bus trip, so each passenger could have more seats, and each seat could have more passengers to keep history).

So now trying to translate this to document-oriented database, I'm not sure how to proceed. I thought about giving Bus a list of references to seats and each seat a list of references to passengers (my application is a seat history application, so I was trying to keep it seat centered), but I'm not sure how to go from a passenger to his seat history. Should I add a list of references to the seats for the passenger collection too, while having a list of references to the passengers in the seats collection, and update both at each turn? Seems like a hacky solution.

Common queries that I'll need to do: get the most popular seat, get all passengers for a seat, get all seats for a passenger (all for a specific bus)

Can anyone help please?

Comment: This question lacks lots of critical information, like which queries are performed most often and which information they retrieve. But in general, references should be avoided in MongoDB, even when this means that you have redundancies in your database. This is because they can not be resolved on the database and thus require additional queries to retrieve them.

Comment: @Philipp Common queries: get the most popular seat, get all passengers for a seat, get all seats for a passenger (all for a specific bus)

Avoided in favour of what?

Comment: You should be able to edit your question. That would allow you to add this new information in a much more detailed way than possible in a comment. References should be avoided by embedding the information in the parent document.

Comment: @Philipp I don't really get it how embedding would work tbh. If I embed the passengers information in the seat information, how do I query all the seats that a passenger had? Or if I embed seats in the passengers, how do I see all passengers that used a particular seat in an efficient way? It doesn't seem to be equivalent with many-to-many relationships that use a junction table

Comment: Are you 100% determined to use MongoDB for this? It sounds like a graph database like Neo4j might be the better solution for your problem.

Comment: @Philipp Why do you think so? I don't wanna switch to that to eventually realise that's not suited either (my manager suggested mongodb and I just went with it)